# How to extract weights and other variable values from tensorflow checkpoint without restoring the graph?

Tags: python, tensorflow, checkpoint

Provided a checkpoint file but no meta graph or code that produced the network, I want to extract the stored values of the variables in the checkpoint file.

So without restoring the graph, how do I extract the values stored in thr checkpoint. I could potentially convert everything from the checkpoint to a dictionary of numpy arrays or something similar.

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution:

```
reader = tf.train.NewCheckpointReader("/path/to/checkpoint")
shapes_dict = reader.get_variable_to_shape_map()  # use it to get the variable names
extracted_values = reader.get_tensor(shapes_dict.keys()[0])
# array([[ 0.       , -1.8053141],
#        [-1.5647348,  0.       ]], dtype=float32)
```

The `tf.train.NewCheckpointReader` is [not really documented](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/NewCheckpointReader) in current documentation of API r1.12.
But you can see the usage example in the source code [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/a6d8ffae097d0132989ae4688d224121ec6d8f35/tensorflow/python/training/saver_test.py#L2407).